# istio rewrite uri with query param

Tags: istio

I am trying to work with `rewrite.uri` which has query parameter. Wondering if this query param `q=1` is supported ? I am getting 503.

```
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /gateway/api/foo
  rewrite:
    uri: /some/svc/bar?q=1
  route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 443
        host: some-svc.example.com
```

I am expecting `curl -I ${baseUrl}/gateway/api/foo` to result into `https://some-svc.example.com/some/svc/bar?q=1`

Comment: The above virtual service is proper w.r.t url rewrite and it will work with query param as its mentioned.  http 503 is for service unavailable where the the actual upstream service is not up and its not because of query parameter.  trust host mentioned in virtual service is matching it in gateway.